# ASP.NET Proper Deployment Procedure

Tags: asp.net, deployment

The web application that a company I'm doing consulting for has all the web files (.aspx, .vb, .ascx, web.config, etc.) but no .sln files or anything of that sort to open in Visual Studio and deploy the site and whatnot.

What's the best way to go about using Visual Studio to redeploy changes I make to this type of system?

Comment: Are they Web Application Projects, or Web Site Projects?

Comment: I think your project is a website project. Try to open the root folder of that project in visual studio and try to run it.

Comment: @Mike is right...Application without .sln files can be a Website Project. so you can just copy the whole folder to IIS. and Run it.

Comment: @Crimsonland - that's not always correct.  The project file is what determines that.  I've seen WAP's checked in to source control without the solution file, for some silly reason.  But all signs point to Website Project in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have stated, it's likely a web site project (likely I say) and you can use the Open Website option within Visual Studio.

Either that, or you could just use the command line and publish it locally before deploying it somewhere...from the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx), it might be something like this:

```
Aspnet_compiler -p "C:\Projects\SomeWebProject\" "C:\Temp\LocalPublishFolder" -errorstack
```